# python-vlc doesn't play audio/video from .py file

Tags: python-3.x, libvlc, python-vlc

I want to make mediaplayer, I choosed **python-vlc** library, but I don't know why I can't play audio/video from ***.py*** file. If I tried make it with cmd and Python Shell all working:

```
>>> import vlc
>>> my_player = vlc.MediaPlayer("d:/Music/song.flac")
>>> my_player.play()
0
```

I write same in ***.py*** file:

```
import vlc

my_player = vlc.MediaPlayer("d:/Music/song.flac")
my_player.play()
```

When I start it in cmd and PyCharm nothing happens and I don't receive any errors, but when I start debuging I receive this:

```
[04521730] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
[04545aa0] mmdevice audio output error: cannot initialize COM (error 0x80010106)
```

P.S. I use ***Python 3.8.0 (32 bit)*** and I have installed ***VLC player (32 bit)*** on ***Windows 10***.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, you need to add a infinite loop or the delay while you want your song on.

For example if you want 10s of music :

```
import vlc
import time

p = vlc.MediaPlayer(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\test.mp3")
p.play()

time.sleep(10)
```

or

```
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer(r"C:\Users\username\Downloads\test.mp3")
p.play()

while True:
     pass
```